# cakephp bindmodel with count

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have two models. 1) User and 2) Post
A user can have many posts. This means, here we will bind both models using hasMany. I am listing users and in that listing, I want to show the #no of posts. I am using cakephp paging. I am not able to list in this way. Any help pls.

User.php (Model)

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    var $hasMany = array('Post');
}
?>
```

Post.php  (Model)

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Post';
    var $primaryKey = 'post_id';
}
?>
```

What should I write for pagination in controller?

I tried `counterCache` option, but didn't get any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use counterCache but for this you need to specify it in the model

in your Post model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array('counterCache' => true)
);
```

Your User table must have an additional field

```
post_count INT()
```

Once this done, each time a user saves/delete a post, it's post_count will be incremented/decremented automatically, which is handy.

The other solution is to add a group clause in you search params

```
'group' => array('Post.id'),
'fields' => array('count(Post.id) as post_count', ...),
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to show? You want to show the post count for each user when displaying a list of users?

If so this does not relate to pagination but rather to the array of data cake retrieves in your controller.

Supposing a controller called index:

```
function index() {
    $this->User->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
}
```

Providing your relationships are correctly set up [they look so] you should be able to find all the user's posts nested in that array. You could then count them and display the result.

The cake debugger is really useful for investigating the data cake outputs to you:

```
debug($yourdataarray)
```

---

However finding each post and counting them sounds a likely performance problem. A solution I've personally done, is to have the add and delete controller in models like your 'Post' add or remove from a post count field in the relevant user's db entry. Then you could just echo that data in a quick and simple way.

Hope that helps.